# How to change legend icon in pie chart, i am using charts_flutter 0.9.0

Tags: flutter, dart, charts, legend

I am trying to change the legend icon from circle to rectangle for my pie chart. I am using the below lines for that but am getting error right away.

```
defaultRenderer: new charts.ArcRendererConfig(
          symbolRenderer: new IconRenderer(Icons.cloud)
      ),
```

I am getting the error (screenshot attached) 
[image]
please help me to change the default icon for the legend in pie chart.

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: @MidhunMP even it is not compile, android studio itself popping the error as like this  -  defaultRenderer: new charts.ArcRendererConfig(
          symbolRenderer: new IconRenderer(Icons.cloud)
      ),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Midhun MP for the hint, actually we need to use CustomSymbolRenderer instead of SymbolRenderer. The below code solved my issue

```
class IconRenderer extends charts.CustomSymbolRenderer {
  final IconData iconData;

  IconRenderer(this.iconData);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, {Size size, Color color, bool enabled}) {
    // Lighten the color if the symbol is not enabled
    // Example: If user has tapped on a Series deselecting it.
    if (!enabled) {
      color = color.withOpacity(0.26);
    }
    return new SizedBox.fromSize(
        size: size, child: new Icon(iconData, color: color, size: 12.0));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because there is no IconRenderer class by default. You have to create a custom SymbolRenderer like below:

```
class IconRenderer extends charts.SymbolRenderer {
  final IconData iconData;

  IconRenderer(this.iconData);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context,
      {Size size, Color color, bool isSelected}) {
    return new SizedBox.fromSize(
        size: size, child: new Icon(iconData, color: color, size: 12.0));
  }
}
```

Reference [legend_custom_symbol](https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/legends/legend_custom_symbol.html)

Comment: Thanks @Midhun MP for the hint, actually we need to use CustomSymbolRenderer instead of SymbolRenderer.